# why my function call many time , with bootstrap modal?

Tags: modal-dialog, typing

My JS :

```
$("#modalADDpp").on('shown',function(e){
    $(this).find('input[type=text]').filter(':first').focus();
    var count = 0;
    alert(count);
    $('#pp_tab a').click(function () {
        $(this).tab('show');
    })
    $("#TenPP").typing({ // jquery for check when finish typing
        start: function(event ,$elem) {
           $(".add-on").remove();
           return false;   
        },
        stop: function (event, $elem) {
            count ++;
            alert(count);
            if(count == 1 )
            {
                Ajax_Check_Name($elem);// Check name same with database by ajax
            }       
            return false;
        },
        delay: 500
    });
    $("#modalADDpp").on('hidden',function(e){
        $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
        $(".add-on").remove();
    });
});
```

I crate $count = 0 at my modal shown . At first time , it work ok . But when hide modal and re-open , $count not = 0 , $count now = 2 => my function will call two time and if close agains , it plus to 3 , 4 ,5 times .

I use

> if(count == 1 )

because i want it run only one time .So it work ok but I dont know where is problem . Need Help !!!

Code of typing.js

```
(function ($) {

    //--------------------
    //  jQuery extension
    //--------------------

    $.fn.typing = function (options) {
        return this.each(function (i, elem) {
            listenToTyping(elem, options);
        });
    };


    //-------------------
    //  actual function
    //-------------------

    function listenToTyping(elem, options) {
        // override default settings
        var settings = $.extend({
            start: null,
            stop: null,
            delay: 400
        }, options);

        // create other function-scope variables
        var $elem = $(elem),
            typing = false,
            delayedCallback;

        // start typing
        function startTyping(event) {
            if (!typing) {
                // set flag and run callback
                typing = true;
                if (settings.start) {
                    settings.start(event, $elem);
                }
            }
        }

        // stop typing
        function stopTyping(event, delay) {
            if (typing) {
                // discard previous delayed callback and create new one
                clearTimeout(delayedCallback);
                delayedCallback = setTimeout(function () {
                    // set flag and run callback
                    typing = false;
                    if (settings.stop) {
                        settings.stop(event, $elem);
                    }
                }, delay >= 0 ? delay : settings.delay);
            }
        }

        // listen to regular keypresses
        $elem.keypress(startTyping);

        // listen to backspace and delete presses
        $elem.keydown(function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46) {
                startTyping(event);
            }
        });

        // listen to keyups
        //$elem.keyup(stopTyping);

        // listen to blurs
        $elem.blur(function (event) {
            stopTyping(event, 0);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to reset the count to 0 ... on hidden or in stop function ...

```
if(count == 1 )
{
   Ajax_Check_Name($elem);// Check name same with database by ajax
   count = 0;
}
```

Or

```
$("#modalADDpp").on('hidden',function(e){
        $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
        $(".add-on").remove();
        count = 0;
});
```

Comment: i tested , count = 0 but when modal open again , it still call two time => count alway = 1 => function still call many times :(